# CSS stylesheet doesn't work in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have a problem with my website. It works fine in all the main browsers except for FireFox. The images are not displaying, the menu isn't working and the overall lay-out isn't showing. I know I haven't placed any alt attributes inside the img tags, but I think this isn't the problem because it works in all the other browsers.

Do you guys have an idea how to solve this?

The link is http://portfolio.io.utwente.nl/student/roosmalenjjvan/

Thanks!

Comment: What Firefox version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you used

```
<link href="css\style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <!--    ^^^ see incorrect slash here -->
```

notice `\` while it should be `/` like

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <!--    ^^^ this is correct slash here -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css path is not correct link http://portfolio.io.utwente.nl/student/roosmalenjjvan/css\style.css

Here you using `<link href="css\style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`
Try this way `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Try use http://portfolio.io.utwente.nl/student/roosmalenjjvan/css/style.css

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your css path...
Currently it is

`<link href="css\style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

please change to

`<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Answer (score 0):

That you are using backslash( \ ) instead of forwardslash(/) in so many places(have a look on below Examples) of your code you just replace the backslashes,

```
<link href="css\style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link rel="icon" href="img\favicon.jpg" type="image/x-icon">

<img src="img\jopvanroosmalen.png">
```

Replace this with

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.jpg" type="image/x-icon">

<img src="img/jopvanroosmalen.png"> and so on
```